# Is it possible to make a (zero-knowledge) proof about the content of an asymmetric encrypted message?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I’m trying to understand the proposal presented in this papger [zkKYC - A solution concept for KYC without knowing your customer, leveraging self-sovereign identity and zero-knowledge proofs](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/907.pdf).

The essence of the paper is on page 10 and specifically in the two sections *zkKYC token* and *Validity proof*.

According to the paper:

1. The *zkKYC token* is a message that is asymmetrically encrypted for a recipient with the public key PK<sub>G</sub>
2. The *validity proof* must be able to proof something about the content of the *zkKYC token*; it must specifically proof that the encrypted message contains certain data

Since I've never seen something similar, my question is this: is such a construct possible? Is it possible to make a zero-knowledge proof about the content of an asymmetric encrypted message at all?